# Regarding the Intersection of $p$-Sylow Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

**The Problem:**

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime divisor of $|G|$.

Prove that a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in every $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

**My Attempt(s):**

Here's a slight modification of an argument I found elsewhere (which I have an issue with): Let $Q \in \mathscr{S}$, where $\mathscr{S}$ is the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Consider the set $A = \bigcap_{g \in G} gQg^{-1}$. Clearly $A \subset Q$ (since $A \subset eQe^{-1} = Q$); so we need just need to show that $A \triangleleft G$. However, it's not entirely clear to me that $A$ is necessarily a $p$-subgroup of $G$, since (it seems to me) it's possible that $A$ might be trivial (where I assume that groups of order 1 are not considered $p$-groups).

If my suspicion is wrong, then the remainder of the proof is fine

Comment: Why are questions so often worded badly? I think you mean "prove that every normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in every $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$", not just that there exists such a normal $p$-subgroup, which is what the question appears to ask.

Comment: @DerekHolt Indeed. It seems I’ve misinterpreted the question (which I would say is worded quite poorly). However, those who’ve commented appeared to’ve interpreted the question “correctly”; so perhaps this is simply a product of my inexperience/ineptitude with the material at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of considering $A$. You need to prove this for any normal $p-$subgroup of $G$, not just for $A$. Indeed, you can show that $A$ contains every normal $p-$subgroup of $G$, however this doesn't seem easier than the original problem.

What I would do is the following. Let $N$ be a normal $p-$subgroup of $G$. Then by the Sylow's Theorems we have that it is contained in a Sylow $p-$subgroup $P$ of $G$, i.e. $N \subseteq P$. Now by the Sylow's Theorem if $Q$ is any Sylow $p-$subgroup we have that $Q = g^{-1}Pg$ for some $g \in G$. So finally:

$$N \subseteq P \implies N = g^{-1}Ng \subseteq g^{-1}Pg = Q$$

Thus $N$ is contained in every Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$.

Comment: By the way the question is phrased, it seems to me that we need to show that, $given$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$, there $exists$ a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ contained in $Q$. Indeed, your proof begins by assuming the existence of a normal $p$-subgroup in $G$ (must there always be one? Probably... but one would have to prove it, I'd imagine).

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude There need not be any normal $p$-subgroups.  For example, $G$ could be simple.  But if there is one, it must be contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude To me it seems clear that the question, as stated, asks you to prove that a normal $p-$subgroup must be contained in all Sylow $p-$subgroup. Here the existence of it is assumed implicitly, i.e. prove the claim given that such normal subgroup exists. As Robert said, according to the way you have understood the question, the claim is false.

Comment: The trivial group is usually considered a $p$-group, so every group has a normal $p$-subgroup.